# When to watch Akakill Theater?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I watched the first episode of Akame ga kill from my plex server and was a a bit surprised that it put Akakill Theater ep 1 as the next episode to watch.

It looks like the air date for each Akakill Theater episode matches the air date the actual show episode from thetvdb.com, so perhaps these shorts aired immediately after each episode aired.

Should these shorts be watched after each main episode?  Are there any spoilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*AkaKill! Theatre* (アカ斬る！劇場) is a short-animation on the official site for a limited time period and it was broadcasted immediately after each episode aired on the TV.

The story mainly reflects the corresponding main episode in a comical way, so there will be no spoiler for future episodes.